# Bokeh: hiding legend items in javascript callback

Tags: bokeh

I have a bokeh chart that starts out with 7 line series in a chart. A select widget changes the data and shows only 4 series via a customjs callback

```
for i in range(7):
    if i < 4:
        js_code += """data['y%d']=data.%s;""" % (i,newseriesnames[i])
    js_code += """line%d.visible = %s;""" % (i,'true' if i < 4 else 'false')
js_code += 'source.change.emit();'
callback = CustomJS(args = args,code=js_code)
select.js_on_change('value',callback)
```

where `line0` through `line6` are the lines in the plot linked to data objects `data['y0']` through `data['y6']` and `select` is a bokeh selector widget.

This works great in the bokeh chart itself, but it doesn't update the legend. The legend is always the same as when it is first rendered. It retains the 7 elements. Even when they are hidden in the chart.

Things I have tried to update the legend:

1. Setting `legend.items[4].renderers[0].visible=false`
2. Setting `legend.items[4].visible=false`
3. Calling `legend.change.emit()`, `legend.items[4].change.emit()`, and `legend.items[4].renderers[0].change.emit()`
4. Overwriting the legend with a different one made using bokeh's python `Legend()` method

Note that I'm not getting any errors with these calls, they just don't produce any difference in the legend. Adding multiple legends and hiding/unhiding them works, except the placement of them is wrong when using `plot.add_layout()`

I would rather not do this using an interactive server, and would rather use the client side to do the switching. My use case is frequent going back and forth, and may want to have offline capability.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I tested this in bokeh 0.12.16 and 0.13.0 in python 3.6.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to make all of the legends beforehand and hide them all

```
for group_name in group_names:
    legend_items[group_name] = make_legend(group_name)
    plot.add_layout(legend_items[group_name], 'right')
for g in legend_items:
    legend_items[g].visible = False
legend_items[group_names[0]].visible = True
```

and then in the callback

```
for f in group_names:
    js_code += """legend_items['%s'].visible = false;""" % f
js_code += 'legend_items[f].visible = true;'
```

I don't think this is a particularly *good* solution, but it works around the fact that I can't seem to update a legend dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.13.0 this is still an open issue, and not possible:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/589

Comment: Is this possible now? I've been having the exact same problem and tried the same solutions + others, no luck so far, I'm getting a bit desperate (tell me if you prefer me to go to discourse for this, I just thought if you had a solution now would be great to post it here :) )

Comment: You can now set the `visible` property of legend items (in Python or JS), as the other answer states.

Comment: I tried that in JS, as the OP, but couldn't have it to work, and testing it in Python yields `AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'visible' to LegendItem, possible attributes are index, js_event_callbacks, js_property_callbacks, label, name, renderers, subscribed_events or tags`, which corresponds to [the doc](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.LegendItem), I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, apologies in advance?

Comment: I was mistaken, this is still an open issue https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9261 Your best bet is to add/remove the individual legend items entirely from the list `Legend.items`.

Comment: Ah I see :) I tried that, does not do anything I could detect visually, even if I delete all of them. My most "successful" attempt was to toggle the `visible` property of the legend items renderer, but this hides the associated glyph (not sure I'm using the right term here, the data basically), does not modify the legend at all. I will follow the issue :) thank you!

Comment: It's not really possible to speculate without actual code. If you are having an issue with swapping out legend items I would suggest a brand new issue with full details and especially a [minimal reproducing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).